# Simplifying a three-index sum that depends only on the differences between indices

Tags: combinatorics, summation

I have the following sum:

\begin{equation}
S = \sum_{i,j,k=1}^La^{|i-j|}a^{|i-k|},
\end{equation}
where, to be clear, all indices run from $1$ to $L$ and $a<1$ is real. I sense that I should somehow change variables to $x=i-j$ and $y=i-k$, but I'm not exactly sure how to do this. I've been trying to think about this in a combinatoric way (imagining a line of length $L$ and the two terms in the sum being subsections of length $|i-j|$ and $|i-k|$), but I didn't get far.

The sum has an analytic solution according to Mathematica.

Comment: If you fix $i$, can you compute $\sum_{j=1}^L a^{|i-j|}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $P$ by taking $i$ to be a constant as follows
$$P=\sum\limits_{k=1}^La^{|i-k|}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^ia^{k-1}+\sum\limits_{k=1}^{L-i}a^{k}=\frac{a^i-1}{a-1}+\frac{a(a^{L-i}-1)}{a-1}=\frac{a^{i}+a^{L-i+1}-a-1}{a-1}$$

$$\sum\limits_{j,k=1}^La^{|i-j|}a^{|i-k|}=\left(\sum\limits_{j=1}^La^{|i-j|}\right) \left(\sum\limits_{k=1}^La^{|i-k|} \right) =P^2$$

$$S=\sum_{i,j,k=1}^La^{|i-j|}a^{|i-k|}= \sum_{i=1}^LP^2=\sum_{i=1}^L  \left(\frac{a^{i}+a^{L-i+1}-a-1}{a-1} \right) ^2$$
$$S=\frac{2a^{2L+2}-2(L+2)a^{L+1}-8a^{L+2}+2(L-2)a^{L+3}+a^4L+2a^3 (L+2)+6a^2-2a(L-2)-L}{(a-1)^3(a+1)}$$
I did the summation with help of [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Csum_%7Bi%3D1%7D%5EL%28%5Cfrac%7Ba%5E%7Bi%7D%2Ba%5E%7BL-i%2B1%7D-a-1%7D%7Ba-1%7D%29%5E2) and I also checked the case when $L=2, a=2$.